# Text over background image is not getting highlighted using z-index

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dark layer over a bright background image. So that the text displays properly.

Below is the snippet:

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="contents" class="bg-light">
  <a href="#" id="movies" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-primary">Movie</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><strong class="text-secondary">Click Here</strong> to discover the movie collections</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="anime" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <span class="text-primary">Anime</span> Collection</h3>
      <p>Check out our anime collections rated and recommended by other viewers. <span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span></p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="ws" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-supplementary">Web-Series</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span> Check out our Web-Series collections rated and recommended by other viewers.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

but the `z-index` is not working properly, and the opacity of the text is also decreased with the image.

Please help how I can increase the visibility of the text inside class "Link-content"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, give the class `link` some sort of display, for example : `display: block;`

Then move to the pseudo-class `::before` and give it a `z-index: -1`

that will get it to work and make the background in the back and the text in the front.

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="contents" class="bg-light">
  <a href="#" id="movies" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-primary">Movie</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><strong class="text-secondary">Click Here</strong> to discover the movie collections</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="anime" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <span class="text-primary">Anime</span> Collection</h3>
      <p>Check out our anime collections rated and recommended by other viewers. <span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span></p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="ws" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-supplementary">Web-Series</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span> Check out our Web-Series collections rated and recommended by other viewers.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If that's not what you are looking for let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's faulty formatting to surround a block element with inline elements. That's why @Ahmad Dalao's solution works, adding `display: block` to the `<a>` tag.

I don't understand. Why can't you just give `.link-content` a background-color? You state "...over a bright background image" but I can't see any code for it.

```css
.link-content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="contents" class="bg-light">
  <a href="#" id="movies" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-primary">Movie</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><strong class="text-secondary">Click Here</strong> to discover the movie collections</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="anime" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <span class="text-primary">Anime</span> Collection</h3>
      <p>Check out our anime collections rated and recommended by other viewers. <span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span></p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="ws" class="link">
    <div class="link-content">
      <h3>My <strong class="text-supplementary">Web-Series</strong> Collection</h3>
      <p><span class="text-secondary">Click Here</span> Check out our Web-Series collections rated and recommended by other viewers.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to create 3 horizontal container block with Flexbox. For each block there will be 3 different image with a text over it. The whole image will be under <a> tag so that it is clickable. But the image I used was so bright that the text on it was not visible at all, so tried to reduce the brightness by adding a dark transparent background it, it worked, but the brightness of the text got reduced too. Seems like I needed to mention z-index = -1 for the postion: absolute too. I missed that part